# Linq to get List with most elements and biggest diff inside it's elements from a List<List<int>>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<List<int>> testLists` 
I want to find the **longest** one **AND** where the numbers inside the list have the **biggest difference**. I know there is a one liner Linq for it, but I can't seem to figure it out.

It has to be something like this:

```
List<int> myMaxTest = testLists
                           .OrderByDescending(s => s.Count) // Longest
                           .ThenBy( s => s.Max(s.Max() - s.Min())) // Biggest Difference
                           .First();  // Only one list from the top
```

This is not correct. It won't compile. My `ThenBy` part is not ok. Can you guys show me the way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `ThenBy` should just be

```
.ThenByDescending(s => s.Max() - s.Min()) // Biggest difference
```

You're currently asking for it to order the lists by each individual list's "highest `Max - Min`". That doesn't make sense, and that (luckily!) means it didn't compile.

Comment: This looks better! Thanks!

Comment: Meanwhile I implemented my own `foreach` kind of search for biggest difference, and I am running on a huge input. The simple `foreach` kind of solution performs much better than the Linq one. How is that possible!?

Comment: @DDan LINQ is geared towards simple code rather than high performance. I'm not at all surprised if you've found a quicker way. For example, you don't need to *sort* a whole huge list to find the one best element, but it's the most obvious way to do it in LINQ.

Comment: Thanks @Rawling for your help and explanation!